# Should it be folk or folks?

Tags: word-choice, grammatical-number

As a British native English speaker I have only ever used the word "folk" as an adjective in phrases such as "folk music" or "folk tales". My unscientific impression is that its use as a synonym for people is increasing in the British media, which prompts the question: *How can I decide whether it should be folk or folks?*

- We should do more for our old folk.

or

- We should do more for our old folks.

..

- Some folk never listen.

or

- Some folks never listen.

Are the two words interchangeable, or are there some clear usage patterns?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

*Folk* is an adjective (e.g. *folk music, folk art*).

*Folk* is a collective noun (e.g. *the folk are uprising*).

*Folks* is a collection of individual folk. The distinction being that "folk" refers to a mass or a mob -- It is referring to the collection or the mass itself.  "Folks" is referring to the plurality of individuals that make up the mass.

In your examples, either *old folk* (the retired population in general) or *old folks* (some set of individuals) would be correct.

In the second example, I would go with "Some folks never listen" as it is the individual people who are not listening, not the crowd in general.

Comment: Thanks. The distinction is subtle but makes sense. My impression, however, is that most (folk/folks) do not make this distinction when using the word. The search results for folk/folks on the Guardian website show no clear usage pattern that reflects this distinction.

Answer (score 7):

Merriam-Webster makes these distinctions for *folk* or *folks* (both of which it lists as plural forms of *folk*):

- plural *folk*

> the masses of people in a homogeneous social group as contrasted with
>   the individual or with a selected class : the great proportion of the
>   members of a people that determines the group character and that tends
>   to preserve its characteristic form of civilization and its customs,
>   arts and crafts, legends, traditions, and superstitions from
>   generation to generation (e.g., the *Folk of the Air*, the *Folk of the Fringe*)

- *folk* or *folks* plural

> a certain kind or class of people -- used with a qualifying adjective
>   or phrase (fine *folks*, parties for the young *folks*)

- *folks* plural

> people indefinitely (*folks* say the house is haunted)