# Singular of "folks"?

Tags: grammatical-number, collective-nouns, gender-neutral

It has been suggested to me that "fellow" is the corresponding singular version of the word "folks" in the context of "hey folks" or "listen folks" but it doesn't have the same gender neutrality.

Comment: Seems this question has been asked before. Need to check past questions on ELU.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/50704/14666

Comment: @Kris, I searched but couldn't find one that provided a singular version, that one is similar though.

Comment: From @John Lawler's comment below, it sounds like it is a frozen plural, at least in the way I am using it. (vocative)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no direct singular word for folks. It is almost like the word "guys" (but more gender neutral).

If an announcer comes out and says, "Howdy folks!" They are speaking to a group or crowd.  You do not say folks when speaking to one person nor do you say folk.  You would simply say "Howdy Mister/Madame/Whatever".  Folks is usually a very friendly word that conveys a down to earth attitude.  I think the closest word to takes its singular place would be **friend**.

If you see a group of people walking by that you know- "Howdy folks".

If you see a person walking by that you know - "Howdy friend" or just "Howdy".  When you gave the "Howdy Folks" to the group walking by the use of folks noted that there was an individual howdy for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this link can help you.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folk

*folks* in the plural form means "people".  The singular of "people" is person, not "fellow".

Comment: The plural of _person_ is _persons_. _People_ has no singular. _Folks_ in the vocative sense, or when meaning _people_ generically, is a frozen plural and doesn't have a singular either.

Comment: I see. I'm curious, then, why _The New Oxford American Dictionary_ lists _people_ and _persons_ as the plurals of _person_.  Incidentally, would you please explain what you mean by "_folks_ in the vocative sense" in this context because I don't know "vocative" in the sense that you're using it.  Thank you.

Comment: _Vocative_ means "direct address", as in _Hey, folks, ..._. It is effectively a noun being used in the second person; normally nouns can only be third person. As for why dictionaries write what they write, my guess would be to indicate that _persons_ and _people_ have the same denotation (though not the same connotation), and that many people use _person_ in the singular when _people_ won't work for them. This does not of course mean that everybody does so, or even that many people do. It's a workaround, that's all.