# Is ‘folk’ a plural form for ‘person’ or not?

Tags: grammatical-number, irregular

In "I Keep Six Honest Serving Men" of Kipling there is a line:

> But different folk have different views;

Notice, the word *folk* here is obviously in plural, but has not -s ending. Kipling had no need to change the grammar in that point - *folk* instead of *folks* does not change neither rhythm nor rhyme.  That means, he **felt** this variant as more suitable for plural here. So, it is absolutely English, I only have to understand it.

But in dictionaries I see:

> folk or folks [PLURAL] INFORMAL people in general (Macmillan)

[Free Oxford](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/folk) gives more interesting variant:

> *folk* (also *folks*) informal [treated as plural] People in general.

So, according to the last, ‘folk’ can be considered as plural of ‘person’. But in the same dictionary, or in several others that I checked, (including paper big Macmillan or Concise Oxford), in the article for ‘person’ you will never see ‘folk’ as a plural form for it.

The question [Should it be folk or folks?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50704) has nothing in common with my question. The mentioned problem is about the plural form of the word `folk`. It is NOT the case of the mentioned Kipling's line. And it is already written in the question. (Obviously, somebody reacts to the titles not reading the content.) I am talking about the `folk` as plural for the `person` -the problem never touched in that other question.

Comment: I asked a similar question here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50704/should-it-be-folk-or-folks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is predicated on the assumptions that synonyms are always totally interchangeable, and that a given dictionary should give an extensive (or even exhaustive) list of synonyms for each headword.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The question has nothing in common with your comment.

Comment: *Folks* is always informal at best, while *folk* is not. It may also be a transatlantic and trans-century difference.

Comment: @TimLymington I am not asking about "folks". I am even explaining, why I am not doing that.

Comment: "[A]ccording to [this dictionary], ‘folk’ can be considered as plural of ‘person’."  NO. As Kate says, _It isn't listed in the dictionary as a plural of 'person' because it's a different word with a similar meaning (just as 'cars' isn't the plural of 'automobile')._  Your question is identical in form to "Is ‘cars’ a plural form for ‘automobile’ or not?"

Comment: [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/folks) shows that 'folk' and 'folks', one singular in form and the other plural in form, are often interchangeable, both taking a plural verb form: << **folk** [noun] (1) [Usually **folks**] ( [both] used with a plural verb): people in general: _Folks say there wasn't much rain last summer._ // (2) [Often **folks**] ([both] used with a plural verb): people of a specified class or group: _country folk; poor folks_ >> [adjusted slightly] // Your 'treated as plural' advice in Lexico means (and should be worded) 'takes a plural verb form'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth If 'folk' is the plural for person, it must be mentioned in the article for 'person'. Both meanings mentioned by you cannot be used for interpretation of the Kipling's line. Sorry, you are not talking on the subject.

Comment: Your misunderstanding is in how certain dictionaries work. Macmillan's << **folk** or **folks** [PLURAL] INFORMAL _people in general_ >> means <<  **folk** or **folks** [both variants take a plural verb form such as 'are' or 'were', not a singular verb form such as 'is'] INFORMAL _people in general_ >>. Compare (my contriving) << car _automobile_ >>. While 'cars' is the plural form of 'car', 'folk' and 'folks' are synonymous etically plural (ie you will have more than one guy) nouns taking plural agreement. One is singular in form, the other plural in form. This is an unusual situation.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, *folk* means *people*, as in the English county names Norfolk and Suffolk, meaning the northern and southern people (of that region). It isn't listed in the dictionary as a plural of *person* because it's a different word with a similar meaning (just as *cars* isn't the plural of *automobile*).

Comment: I thought that, too, till now. Please, show, how your explanation a) works for the Kipling's line and b) sits with the article of the Free Oxford. As far as I see, you are reacting to the title, not even trying to answer the question.

Comment: I don't understand your  hostile attitude. Kipling's line means 'different people have different views', and Free Oxford says that _folk_ is the word and _folks_ a variant of it. The plural of _person_ is _people_; as Edwin says, you can't expect a dictionary to list all possible synonyms.

Comment: 1. I am merely reminding you the rules of the logic. It is not aggression. 2. **Now** you **are** talking on the subject of the question. And yes, this reading is the only one that does not suppose that Kipling breaks the grammar rules. 3. I never asked for the list of synonyms (that **explain** the meaning of the nest word), but I do suppose that dictionary shows all correct irregular plural forms for a word. And I had never met with another irregular plural not covered by the appropriate dictionary article. Even in the weakest dictionaries.

Comment: But 'folk' is not an irregular plural; as I said in my original answer, it is a different word. There is no question of Kipling's breaking the rules, or any possible different reading. You are making difficulties where none exist.